# Endeca Searchable Character v/s Phrase search

Tags: search, e-commerce, endeca

Facing conflict between endeca searchable character & phrase search.

I have a word sequence for eg. *hello "world*. "(Double quote) is needed here.

**1)** Phrasing " (double qoutes special character) is enabled for search by putting it into pipeline file **Project_name.search_chars.xml**.

**2)** If I remove " from Project_name.search_chars.xml , phrasing is working properly but I am not able to search the term containing " (quotes special character in it.)

I have also tried some escape characters -
1) *"hello ""world"*
2) *"hello \"world"*
3) *"hello """world"*

Nothing seems working here for me.

Can anyone suggest any configuration solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to be able to search for " but not mess up the phrase functionality which under the hood creates quoted strings.

A possible work around is to perform substitution when loading the data into endeca as well as during search.

Replace the " character in your data set with something that is not currently used (a ~ is a likely choice) and make that character searchable. Next have some pre-process code replace any incoming " characters with the selected substitution so that endeca knows how to process it.

Once this is done phrase will continue to behave as expected.

We have successfully implemented this type of solution with the dash character.